# Have multiple working Signature panels

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, signature

I have a form that needs to be signed by three people. I initially set it up to be signed by one person, but found out I needed three. I can't get all three to work.

Canvas Containers:

```
<div class="rowElem">
    <div id="container2">
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="rowElem">
    <div id="container3">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rowElem">
    <div id="container4">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>


       (function (ns) {
    "use strict";

    ns.SignatureControl = function (options) {
        var containerId = options && options.canvasId || "container2",
            callback = options && options.callback || {},
            label = options && options.label || "Teacher Signature",
            cWidth = options && options.width || "300px",
            cHeight = options && options.height || "300px",
            btnClearId,
            canvas,
            ctx;

        function initCotnrol() {
            createControlElements();
            wireButtonEvents();
            canvas = _("signatureCanvas");
            canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", pointerDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", pointerUp, false);
            ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");            
        }

        function createControlElements() {            
            var signatureArea = document.createElement("div"),
                labelDiv = document.createElement("div"),
                canvasDiv = document.createElement("div"),
                canvasElement = document.createElement("canvas"),
                buttonsContainer = document.createElement("div"),
                buttonClear = document.createElement("button");

            labelDiv.className = "signatureLabel";
            labelDiv.textContent = label;

            canvasElement.id = "signatureCanvas";
            canvasElement.clientWidth = cWidth;
            canvasElement.clientHeight = cHeight;
            canvasElement.style.border = "solid 2px black";
            canvasElement.style.background = "white";

            buttonClear.id = "btnClear";
            buttonClear.textContent = "Clear Signature Panel";

            canvasDiv.appendChild(canvasElement);
            buttonsContainer.appendChild(buttonClear);

            signatureArea.className = "signatureArea";
            signatureArea.appendChild(labelDiv);
            signatureArea.appendChild(canvasDiv);
            signatureArea.appendChild(buttonsContainer);

            _(containerId).appendChild(signatureArea);
        }

        function pointerDown(evt) {
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY);
            canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", paint, false);
        }

        function pointerUp(evt) {
            canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", paint);
            paint(evt);
        }

        function paint(evt) {
            ctx.lineTo(evt.offsetX, evt.offsetY);
            ctx.stroke();
        }

        function wireButtonEvents() {
            var btnClear = _("btnClear");
            btnClear.addEventListener("click", function () {
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            }, false);
        }

        function getSignatureImage() {
            return ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;
        }

        return {
            init: initCotnrol,
            getSignatureImage: getSignatureImage
        };
    }
})(this.ns = this.ns || {});
```

This is the initiator script:

```
    function teacherSig() {
            var signature = new ns.SignatureControl({ containerId: 'container2', callback: function () {
                } 
            });
            signature.init();
            _('btnClear').className = "greyishBtn";
        }

        window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', teacherSig, false);
</script>
```

The "_" are a variable set in another file for document.getElementById - I already know that works, I'm using it in all my js files.

I tried duplicating the initiator script and changing the function name/element names, but it did not do any good.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If anyone knows a better way to do this, I can try that as well. I'm running out of time on this project, and this was something the client added on in the end. If anyone knows another solution, a plugin or anything for multiple, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you ask for a better way to do it I would like suggest you use [easyCanvasJS](http://easyCanvasJS.com/) for this which setups up most of the non-trivial things but allow you to use context and canvas as usual.

**[ONLINE FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/WRCrx/)**

For three signature boxes all you need to do is the following (keeping your original HTML code as shown in the post:

```
/// setup three canvases referencing parent Id and setting size:
var ez1 = new easyCanvas('container2', 350, 100),
    ez2 = new easyCanvas('container3', 350, 100),
    ez3 = new easyCanvas('container4', 350, 100);

/// common handler when mouse is held down, this = current easyCanvas instance
ez1.onmousemove =  ez2.onmousemove =  ez3.onmousemove = function(x, y) {
    /// instead of this.ctx.moveTo etc.. :
    this.strokeLine(this.prevX, this.prevY, x, y);
}
```

Now you have three boxes where you can sign into. The `strokeLine` is a short hand function for drawing a line, `prevX/Y` are stored internally on the `easyCanvas` instance and `x` and `y` is already corrected relative to canvas.

(To access the canvas you would just reference `ez.canvas` and for context `ez.ctx` or `ez.context`).

For demo's sake I threw in some save buttons in the HTML to allow you to save the canvas as an image:

```
save1.addEventListener('click', function(){download(ez1,1)}, false);
save2.addEventListener('click', function(){download(ez2,2)}, false);
save3.addEventListener('click', function(){download(ez3,3)}, false);

function download(ez, index) {
    /// show a save dialog with filename to save image here as png
    ez.download('Signature' + index + '.png');
}
```

If you instead need the data internally you could do this:

```
ez.canvas.toDataURL();
```

instead for each of the instances.

Update - for example: on a single save button do:

```
function saveSignatures() {

    var sig1 = ez1.canvas.toDataURL();
    var sig2 = ez2.canvas.toDataURL();
    var sig3 = ez3.canvas.toDataURL();

    saveByAjax(sig1, sig2, sig3); // some ajax function to save the data
}
```

Disclaimer: [easyCanvas](http://easyCanvasJS.com/) for JavaScript is made by myself, is free and licensed under GPL-3.0.

Comment: And if I want to save all three at one time? I'm already saving the image to a folder using ajax.

Comment: @Jack just use a single button where you extract the image as a data-uri from each instance (see updated answer and fiddle). The ajax function in my example is pseudo, just use what you already have instead.

Comment: Thanks! And just to verify, `var sig1 = ez1.canvas.toDataURL(),
        sig2 = ez2.canvas.toDataURL(),
        sig3 = ez3.canvas.toDataURL();` captures the signature for me to save, right?

Comment: @Jack that's correct. But in case - These are data-uri's (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). If you just want the binary part (the image itself) you will need to cut off its header and decode the base64 to binary format (I would recommend to do this on server). There is no direct way around this. You can optionally store and send back the whole string as-is and set it directly on a image element's src attribute to show the signature (the browser will decode it for you).

Comment: Will this work on tablets? The one I currently have does not work on an iPad.

Comment: @Jack if the browser you use with it supports canvas it should work (the lib uses standard canvas element). You can also check the console of the browser to see if any errors occurred.

Comment: Hey man, for whatever reason, the divs are remaining empty. I tweaked the code to match what I was working on and thought that was the problem, so I copied and pasted and the canvases wont show up.